# TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have several select-box and data of each of them returns based on previous select-box option.

Previously i had 3 select-box and everything was working just fine, now i need to add extra select-box those old select-boxes still working fine but this new one returns `TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined`

## screenshot

Maybe this image can explain better

[image: one]

## Code

`Javascript`

To make code shorter and cleaner i removed unnecessary parts and commented what each part does.

The part of current issue is `function substricsfunction(){`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#province').on('change', function() { 
          var provinceID = $(this).val();
         //ajax cal to return city names when state name changes (no. 2 image above)
      }); 
  });


  jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('body').on('change', '#city', function(e){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

       var cityID = $(this).val();

       var weight = ["{{$totalWeight}}"];
        if(cityID) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('rajaajax') }}/'+weight+'/'+encodeURI(cityID),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                //return data in select-box (no.4 image above)
              }
            });

            //custom function
            myfunction();
            substricsfunction();
        }else{
          $('select[name="postchoose"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Pilih</option>");
        }
    });
  });



  function myfunction(){
      //return some more data in select-box (no.4 image above)
  };

  //newpart ( we work on this now )
  function substricsfunction(){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });
       var hfg = $(this).val();
        if(hfg) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('rajaajaxsubdistrict') }}/'+encodeURI(hfg),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                //
                $('select[name="subdistrict"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Pilih</option>");
                $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                    $.each(value.data, function(key2, value2) {
                    $('select[name="subdistrict"]').append('<option id="subdistrict" class="form-control"  value="'+ value2.subdistrict_id +'">'+ value2.subdistrict_name +'</option>');
                     });
                });
                //
              }
            });
        }
    };
  //newpart

</script>
```

## More to know

**URL** `{{ url('rajaajaxsubdistrict') }}/'+encodeURI(hfg)` which is equal to `site.trg/rajaajaxsubdistrict/27` returns data as

[image: two]

So my error `TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined` isn't about back-end whatever is wrong is just about this function.

Any idea?

Comment: `$(this).val();` seems strange, as you call the function like `substricsfunction()` and `this` is `window` in this case.

Comment: @RolandStarke so i change `var hfg = $(this).val();` to what exactly?

Comment: Could you first confirm if that thats the problem? like `console.log(hfg)`

Comment: @RandyCasburn nothing prints as `console.log(hfg);`

Comment: Where is nodeName in your code?

Comment: @epascarello i don't have such thing, it's just the error that comes up

Comment: Let's see that portion of the HTML.

Comment: I made this video of errors and when they happen https://streamable.com/l620c

Comment: @RandyCasburn `<select class="form-control" name="subdistrict" id="subdistrict">
                                <option value="">{{ __('frontend.selcity') }}</option>
                              </select>` I also shared small video in comment above  maybe that helps.

Comment: Where is the event handler for the `subdistrict` select?

Comment: if you type `$(window).val()` into the console you see that you get the same error, replace `this` with the selector of the input you want to get the value of.

Comment: guys i solved it i got the id by `var hfg = $("#city option:selected").val();` now it's working just fine. Thank you all.

Comment: `$('#city').val()` should ne enough.

Comment: @RolandStarke yes that works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I changed `var hfg = $(this).val();` to `var hfg = $("#city option:selected").val();` and fixes my issue